# How to generate valid Sudoku board? [ and difficulty rating ]

Tags: c#, algorithm, sudoku

I'm working on a Sudoku programm. For the moment, I can generate a valid Sudoku board, but I can't know if I generate an easy or hard one.

Here is my aproach:

I start with generating the full board. The final board is empty.

I start fill 21 random cells with values from full board.

I find all solutions of the final board, and for each cell, count how many times the solutions differ by the full board, pick the one with the most, and fill it. ( This idea is taken from here : [How to generate Sudoku boards with unique solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924216/how-to-generate-sudoku-boards-with-unique-solutions)  first answer )

Do this, untill you have only one solution.

Now, I don't know if this aproach with 21 random cells is the right one. Sometimes I have a lot of solutions after first 21 random cells, other times a few.

For the moment I generate a final board on an average time of: 0,3 seconds.

I would like to tell me a different and fast method, beside this one, with 21 random cells, maybe where I can rank the difficulty of the board.

Thank you!

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588962/brute-force-algorithm-for-creation-of-sudoku-board

Comment: From what I read, the link above talks about generating a full sudoku board, with all the cells filled, and some talking about sudoku solver. I did those steps... Thx anyway

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this code that implements 3 levels of Difficulty{Easy, Medium, Hard}

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SuperSudoku
{
    public enum Difficulty
    {
        Easy, Medium, Hard
    }

    class PuzzleGenerator
    {
        private PuzzleSolver puzzleSolver;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public PuzzleGrid PermaGrid;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public PuzzleGrid SolutionGrid;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private Difficulty difficulty;

        /// <summary>
        /// This constructs a puzzle generator class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="difficultyIn">The difficulty to generate a new puzzle.</param>
        public PuzzleGenerator(Difficulty difficultyIn)
        {
            puzzleSolver = new PuzzleSolver();
            difficulty = difficultyIn;
        }

        public PuzzleGrid InitGrid()
        {                 //Randomly fill in the first row and column of puzzlegrid
            PuzzleGrid tempGrid = new PuzzleGrid { };      //temporary grid to assign values into
            int row = 0;                           //variable for navigating 'rows'
            int col = 0;                        //variable for navigating 'columns'
            int newVal;                                  //value to place into grid
            bool solved;
            List<int> valueSet = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(-9, 9));   //range 
                                     //of numbers that can be added to the grid
            List<int> valueSet2 = new List<int>(); //placeholder values in column 0
            Random rnd = new Random(); //random variable for choosing random number
            int randIndex = 0;       //index in valueSet/valueSet2 that is accessed
            randIndex = rnd.Next(0,8); //get a random number and place in grid(0,0)
            newVal = valueSet[randIndex]; 
            tempGrid.InitSetCell(row,col,newVal);
            valueSet.Remove(newVal);              //remove paced value from options
            for(row = 1; row < 9; row++)
            { //fills in column 0 with remaining possible values, storing in place-
              //holder as it goes so as to preserve when placing in row 0 later
                randIndex = rnd.Next(0,valueSet.Count);
                newVal = valueSet[randIndex];
                valueSet2.Add(newVal);
                valueSet.Remove(newVal);
                tempGrid.InitSetCell(row,col,newVal);
            }
               row = 0;                                               //reset row to 0
            for(col = 1; col < 3; col++)
            {        //fills in col 1,2 of row 0, checking that don't duplicate the
                                                  //values in rows 1,2 of col 0
                randIndex = rnd.Next(0,valueSet2.Count);
                newVal = valueSet2[randIndex];
                while((newVal == tempGrid.Grid[1,0]||(newVal == tempGrid.Grid[2,0])))
                {
                    randIndex = rnd.Next(0,valueSet2.Count);
                    newVal = valueSet2[randIndex];
                }
                valueSet2.Remove(newVal);
                tempGrid.InitSetCell(row,col,newVal);
            }
            for(col = 3; col < 9; col++)
            {           //fill in remainder of row 0 with remaining possible values
                randIndex = rnd.Next(0,valueSet2.Count);
                newVal = valueSet2[randIndex];
                valueSet2.Remove(newVal);
                tempGrid.InitSetCell(row,col,newVal);
            }
            do
            {
                puzzleSolver = new PuzzleSolver();
                puzzleSolver.SolveGrid((PuzzleGrid)tempGrid.Clone(), false); //Slv to fill remainder of grid
                SolutionGrid = puzzleSolver.SolutionGrid;
            } while (SolutionGrid == null || SolutionGrid.IsBlank());
            PermaGrid = Blanker(SolutionGrid);       //call Blanker to carry out the
            return PermaGrid;         //blanking of fileds,then return the grid to user to solve
        }
        //  Call SolveGrid to solve puzzlegrid
        //Store solved gamegrid as the correct solution in solutiongrid

        public PuzzleGrid Blanker(PuzzleGrid solvedGrid)
        {                          //enable blanking of squares based on difficulty
            PuzzleGrid tempGrid; 
            PuzzleGrid saveCopy;
                                        //temporary grids to save between tests
            bool unique = true;          //flag for if blanked form has unique soln
            int totalBlanks = 0;                          //count of current blanks
            int tries = 0;                  //count of tries to blank appropriately
            int desiredBlanks;            //amount of blanks desired via difficulty
            int symmetry = 0;                                       //symmetry type
            tempGrid = (PuzzleGrid)solvedGrid.Clone(); 
                                                //cloned input grid (no damage)
            Random rnd = new Random();         //allow for random number generation

            switch (difficulty)           //set desiredBlanks via chosen difficulty
            {
            case Difficulty.Easy: //easy difficulty
                desiredBlanks = 40;
                break;
            case Difficulty.Medium: //medium difficulty
                desiredBlanks = 45;
                break;
            case Difficulty.Hard: //hard difficulty
                desiredBlanks = 50;
                break;
            default: //easy difficulty
                desiredBlanks = 40;
                break;
            }

            symmetry = rnd.Next(0, 2);                   //Randomly select symmetry
            do
            {          //call RandomlyBlank() to blank random squares symmetrically
                saveCopy = (PuzzleGrid)tempGrid.Clone();     // in case undo needed
                tempGrid = RandomlyBlank(tempGrid, symmetry, ref totalBlanks);
                           //blanks 1 or 2 squares according to symmetry chosen
                puzzleSolver = new PuzzleSolver();
                unique = puzzleSolver.SolveGrid((PuzzleGrid)tempGrid.Clone(), true);         // will it solve uniquely?
                if(!unique)
                {
                    tempGrid = (PuzzleGrid)saveCopy.Clone();
                    tries++;
                }
            } while((totalBlanks < desiredBlanks) && (tries < 1000));
            solvedGrid = tempGrid;
            solvedGrid.Finish();
            return solvedGrid;
        }

        public PuzzleGrid RandomlyBlank(PuzzleGrid tempGrid, int sym, ref int blankCount)
        {
            //blank one or two squares(depending on if on center line) randomly
            Random rnd = new Random(); //allow random number generation
            int row = rnd.Next(0, 8); //choose randomly the row
            int column = rnd.Next(0, 8); //and column of cell to blank
            while (tempGrid.Grid[row, column] == 0) //don't blank a blank cell
            {
                row = rnd.Next(0, 8);
                column = rnd.Next(0, 8);
            }
            tempGrid.InitSetCell(row, column, 0); //clear chosen cell
            blankCount++; //increment the count of blanks
            switch (sym)
            {
                    //based on symmetry, blank a second cell
                case 0: //vertical symmetry
                    if (tempGrid.Grid[row, 8 - column] != 0) //if not already blanked
                        blankCount++; //increment blank counter
                    tempGrid.InitSetCell(row, 8 - column, 0); //blank opposite cell
                    break;
                case 1: //horizontal symmetry
                    if (tempGrid.Grid[8 - row, column] != 0)
                        blankCount++;
                    tempGrid.InitSetCell(8 - row, column, 0);
                    break;
                case 2: //diagonal symmetry
                    if (tempGrid.Grid[column, row] != 0)
                        blankCount++;
                    tempGrid.InitSetCell(column, row, 0);
                    break;
                default: //diagonal symmetry
                    if (tempGrid.Grid[row, 8 - column] != 0)
                        blankCount++;
                    tempGrid.InitSetCell(column, row, 0);
                    break;
            }
            return tempGrid;
        }

    }
}
```

the rest of [code is in here](http://super-sudoku.googlecode.com/svn-history/r61/trunk/SuperSudoku/)

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 5 version

The simply code I have, here you go

First, create the function:

```
func getNumberSudoku() -> [[Int]] {
    // Original number
    let originalNum = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    // Create line 1 to 9 and shuffle from original
    let line1 = originalNum.shuffled()
    let line2 = line1.shift(withDistance: 3)
    let line3 = line2.shift(withDistance: 3)
    let line4 = line3.shift(withDistance: 1)
    let line5 = line4.shift(withDistance: 3)
    let line6 = line5.shift(withDistance: 3)
    let line7 = line6.shift(withDistance: 1)
    let line8 = line7.shift(withDistance: 3)
    let line9 = line8.shift(withDistance: 3)
    // Final array
    let renewRow = [line1,line2,line3,line4,line5,line6,line7,line8,line9]
    // Pre-shuffle for column
    let colSh1 = [0,1,2].shuffled()
    let colSh2 = [3,4,5].shuffled()
    let colSh3 = [6,7,8].shuffled()
    let rowSh1 = [0,1,2].shuffled()
    let rowSh2 = [3,4,5].shuffled()
    let rowSh3 = [6,7,8].shuffled()
    // Create the let and var
    let colResult = colSh1 + colSh2 + colSh3
    let rowResult = rowSh1 + rowSh2 + rowSh3
    var preCol: [Int] = []
    var finalCol: [[Int]] = []
    var prerow: [Int] = []
    var finalRow: [[Int]] = []
    // Shuffle the columns
    for x in 0...8 {
        preCol.removeAll()
        for i in 0...8 {
            preCol.append(renewRow[x][colResult[i]])
        }
        finalCol.append(preCol)
    }
    // Shuffle the rows
    for x in 0...8 {
        prerow.removeAll()
        for i in 0...8 {
            prerow.append(finalCol[x][rowResult[i]])
        }
        finalRow.append(prerow)
    }
    // Final, create the array into the [[Int]].
    return finalRow
}
```

Then usage:

```
var resultSudoku = [[Int]]
resultSudoku = getNumberSudoku()
```